# nativescript reload page content when moving between tabs

Tags: mobile-application, angular2-nativescript

Using Nativescript with Angular.
When switching between tabs of a tabview can we force the content of the tab be reloaded?

```
  this.router.navigate(["/home", {outlets: { trustoutlet: ['trust']}}])
```

Tab View

```
<TabView #tabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" selectedColor="#d8292f">
    <ng-template tabItem title="Dashboard" iconSource="{{dashActive === true ? 'res://dashboard' : 'res://dashboard'}}">
        <StackLayout>
    <router-outlet name="dashoutlet"></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template tabItem title="Properties" iconSource="{{propActive === true ? 'res://properties' : 'res://properties'}}">
        <StackLayout>
    <router-outlet name="propoutlet"></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template tabItem title="Housekeeping" iconSource="{{trustActive === true ? 'res://trust' : 'res://trust'}}">
        <StackLayout>
    <router-outlet name="trustoutlet"></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template tabItem title="More" iconSource="{{moreActive === true ? 'res://more' : 'res://more'}}">
        <StackLayout>
    <router-outlet name="moreoutlet"></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</TabView>
```

What i want to be able to have is the content of the Housekeeping page to be refreshed when the user navigates to it.

Is it possible to remove its content from the cache before the next time they navigate to it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to create an empty page component and load that to each of the other tabs that are not visible, that way when the next tab it clicked it will reload the component over the empty page, this also fixes the issue of different actionbars on each tab. By not having an actionbar on the empty page, when the next page is loaded it's actionbar is used in place of the previous one.

These are the additional child routes on the tabbed page.

```
{ path: 'freshhouse', component: NewPageComponent, outlet: 'trustoutlet'},
{ path: 'freshprop', component: NewPageComponent, outlet: 'propoutlet'},
{ path: 'freshdash', component: NewPageComponent, outlet: 'dashoutlet'},
{ path: 'fresh', component: NewPageComponent, outlet: 'moreoutlet'},
```

newpage.html i just put an activity indicator on it, although it should never be seen.

```
<GridLayout #main_content rows="auto, *" class="main_content">
  <StackLayout class="indicator" [busy]="isLoading" row="0" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center" >
<ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading" row="0" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

the Tab View

```
<TabView #tabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)" selectedColor="#d8292f">
```

The onIndexChanged function

```
public onIndexChanged(args) {
     .......
  this.router.navigate(["/home", {outlets: { dashoutlet: ['freshdash'], propoutlet: ['freshprop'],  trustoutlet: ['freshhouse'], moreoutlet: ['more'] }}])
     .......
}
```

If anyone else has a simpler solution then feel free to respond.